# how do i create a dyanmic 2d array in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var Mydata= [
    {
        value: 1,
        label: "One"
    },
    {
        value: 2,
        label: "Two"
    },
    {
        value: 3,
        label: "Three"
    },
    {
        value: 4,
        label: "Four"
    },
    {
        value: 5,
        label: "Five"
    }

];
```

i need to create this dyanamically using js or jquery

Comment: By "dynamically", what do you mean?

Comment: This is not a 2D array, this is actually an 1D array of objects.

Comment: Create an object with value and label then push that object to array..

Comment: Here is a [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/29q7z0e4/).

Answer (score 1):

> In `loop`, push `object` in `array`. To get equivalent of the number in words use [`toWords.js`](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm)

Try this:

```js
var len = 10;

var Mydata = [];
for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
  Mydata.push({
    value: i,
    label: toWords(i.toString())
  });
}
console.log(Mydata);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://javascript.about.com/library/toword.js"></script>
```